# Why has this Animal Farm question been reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen, moderation

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16127/what-do-the-other-farmers-symbolize-in-animal-farm) about Animal Farm has just been [reopened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/16127/timeline#history_937a2ac4-af5e-428c-ad19-520e5aea6a3e) by site moderator Rand al'Thor.

It was [closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/16127/timeline#history_97ce01f5-2857-4867-ae25-7a88f41aac8f) in 2015 as off-topic due to '*not being about science fiction or fantasy*' in line with the [accepted policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/is-animal-farm-on-topic) about Animal Farm [not being on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6474/20774).

**Why has it been reopened?**

Answer (score 23):

Sorry about that. **The question has now been re-closed.**

But since you asked *why*, here's the full sequence of events:

1. Hamlet originally posted the question on the old Literature Stack Exchange, back in **2011**. (Notice that the answer is from someone with a greyed-out username, as happens with migrated posts.)
2. When the old Literature Stack Exchange was closed down in **2012**, the question was migrated here to SFF as part of [this effort](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746/31394) to save useful questions from there.
3. A new incarnation of Literature Stack Exchange [restarted](http://literature.stackexchange.com) just now in **2017**. Yay, great news, but it caused the links to break on all questions from Lit.1 which had been migrated to other sites: the "migrated from ..." banner links to a page on http://literature.stackexchange.com, but of course that page is now a totally different question on the new Literature site.
4. This issue was raised on [Literature meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/17), and Shog9 provided the solution: "*If you come across these, flag 'em and ask a moderator to clear the migration history.*"
5. A user flagged the Animal Farm question for this reason, so I cleared the migration history as requested. Apparently this also had the unexpected side-effect of reopening the question.

TL;DR: **it was an accident.** Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: I assumed it was something like that.

Comment: What an unusual number of votes for this. Meta, you got some 'splainin' to to do.