# Can scifi id questions from movies SE be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, support, story-identification

Since movies SE have decided to ban id question and delete all the existing ones, I'm asking if it's possible to save part of its archive (scifi related questions) by migrating them here? And if it's possible how to do so (I'm not familiar with how migrating works)?

Comment: Thx, TARS. Still I don't get how to nominate a question for migration.

Comment: Note that the answered questions will NOT be **deleted** in general. Just *closed/locked*

Comment: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions?cb=1

Comment: @Paulie_D - What do you think "_Cleaning up the existing questions_" means?

Comment: @madmada - The only way to get a migration from movies is by getting a moderator to do it. You can attract their attention with a custom moderator flag.

Comment: @TARS Now that the situation at M&TV has changed, I'm not sure if this should be closed as a dupe. The previous question was about migrating ID questions which were closed on M&TV for not being detailed enough; now it's *all* sci-fi/fantasy ID questions on M&TV which are fair game.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, this should definitely be done.**

When the old Literature SE was shut down (not to be confused with [the new one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)), all of its sci-fi and fantasy questions were [migrated here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746/31394), so that the content could be kept in a place where it's wanted rather than irrecoverably lost. (This even included [some ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1785/31394).)

The current situation is similar, except that it's not an entire site being shut down but only around 1/3 of one (by question count). **Any questions which would otherwise be deleted on M&TV, and which would be welcome here, should certainly be migrated.** That's the way migration works: if a question is off-topic on the site where it's posted, but would be both on-topic and good quality on another site, then there's no reason not to shunt it over.

*Note that this doesn't necessarily cover ALL sci-fi and fantasy ID questions on M&TV. That site gets a lot of very low-quality ID questions, and some of them would doubtless be too crappy for us as well. Let's not go overboard here.*

As for how to nominate a question for migration (which you mentioned in comments), the answer is simple: just **flag it for mod attention over there**. It's the M&TV mods who need to migrate these questions. But they have no reason not to do so if they know a question would be welcomed here (e.g. if it was flagged by someone who knows SFF's scope well), so there shouldn't be any disagreement.

As a CM said in a [related meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4138) on another site about migrating ID questions to SFF:

> if anyone who is really active at SF&F and familiar with their guidelines sees something here they definitely think is a good fit there, great! Flag it!

I've already [opened a meta post on M&TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4090/27759) about this too.

Comment: *"Note that this doesn't necessarily cover ALL sci-fi and fantasy ID questions on M&TV. That site gets a lot of very low-quality ID questions, and some of them would doubtless be too crappy for us as well. Let's not go overboard here."* - And this is where the problems start. Noone's going to sieve out crap for absolutely no benefit. Implementing a reasonable quality filter for *that site itself* turned out not worth the effort. Implementing a quality filter for a third party site seems even less worth it, especially for 5000 old questions.

Comment: @TARS Nobody's proposing that you (M&TV mods or users) implement a quality filter for us. All you have to do is act on flags as they come to your attention, as discussed [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4090/27759) and [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4138) for example.

Comment: Remember even mods can't migrate questions older than 60 days. And from what I hear, the movies mods are quite uncooperative in migrating those questions to here anyway. Probably best if we convince SE to automatically send them here rather than just closing.

Comment: Incidentally, the old literature cleanup post you linked is full of broken links; would be nice to get it spiffed up (or even just remove all the broken links).  See my comment here: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/literature-is-closing-what-questions-should-we-migrate-here#comment37994_1747