# Which ID questions do we want from Movies & TV?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, migration

Our sister site [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) has decided to [ban ID questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/27759). All of their thousands of existing ID questions are now closed and locked, and many of them are [slated for deletion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4121/27759) over the coming weeks. Some proportion of them are about sci-fi and fantasy films, and much of this content would be considered high-quality by SFF's standards. It seems a shame to let it all be destroyed when [we're perfectly willing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11631/31394) to house it here where it's on-topic.

The [response from a CM](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4103/27759) to my meta post over there was that they're willing to migrate some of this content to us, but only in a single mass operation, rather than by way of us manually flagging questions on M&TV. This is what we should do as a first step to migration:

> Start on your meta. Build a list of questions that you think would benefit from being migrated to your site and collect some reasons along with each one. Don't just say "all questions in our tags!". That's neither going to happen nor is a good approach - do you really want to swarm your new community with old content?
>
> This is also your opportunity to edit old questions to make them more in line with your scope and standards.

---

### Let's make a list: which M&TV unwanted ID questions do we want here?

> **Criteria:**
>
> - must be about **sci-fi or fantasy**
> - must be unwanted by M&TV (**either a score of <5, or no answers scoring >2, or both**)
> - must be high-quality by SFF's standards (i.e. **[enough details for a unique match](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11420/31394)**)

---

[This search](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentify-this-*%5D+score%3A..4+is%3Aq) gives all ID questions scoring <5 on M&TV, while [this search](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentify-this-*%5D+is%3Aq+isanswered%3Ano) gives all unanswered ID questions on M&TV. (Even the union of these may potentially miss some candidates - questions with high scores and low-scoring answers - but they're the best I have for now. I'm waiting to hear back from a guy who has a better query which he's willing to share.)

M&TV also has [science-fiction](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tags, but I don't know how consistently these are used.

---

**Let's do this as soon as possible, before all the content gets nuked on M&TV!**

Comment: *"...do you really want to swarm your new community with old content?"* - Sure. Why the hell not if it's on-topic?

Comment: Could the downvoter please elaborate what they dislike?

Comment: @Edlothiad - some people *really* don't like ID questions <===== *me*

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Yes, but do you begrudge those who do like them?

Answer (score 15):

All of the questions below meet *our* main criteria for an acceptable migration candidate;

- That there's discernible SF/F content
- That they're uniquely identifiable

---

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82356/help-me-identify-this-horrible-vampire-movie

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68644/animated-series-that-tells-stories-based-on-fairy-tales-by-grimm-brothers-hans

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60665/horror-movie-about-a-demon-or-telekinetic-boy-who-kills-his-family-members

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74537/what-show-did-yakko-wakko-and-dot-make-frequent-silent-cameos-in

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83911/zombie-outbreak-movie-with-a-cure

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79099/sci-fi-movie-about-a-shapeshifter

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84023/i-remember-important-parts-of-this-movie-but-not-the-title

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83213/movie-about-ants-that-eat-everything-and-grow-to-be-huge

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83602/identify-this-movie-about-ghouls-in-a-desert-and-a-car-stonehenge

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81993/movie-about-a-group-of-monster-disguised-as-human-attacking-a-building

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78773/identify-a-short-animated-movie-about-a-walking-tree-in-red-shoes

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80797/short-horror-movie-6-mins-on-youtube

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/low-budget-d-list-movie-with-werewolf-emo-guy-and-mystical-girl-of-his-dreams

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60432/old-asian-movie-about-foreseeing-the-future

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82795/a-documentary-or-short-film-set-in-medieval-europe-about-a-king-who-impales-enem

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82981/a-korean-horror-movie-in-2004-about-a-ghost-trying-to-protect-her-unborn-baby-fr

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83044/french-film-where-the-wife-girlfriend-changes-every-morning-after-sex

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83272/60s-or-70s-western-horror-film-that-goes-from-b-w-to-color

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70342/animated-film-about-a-group-of-people-from-a-television-show

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57589/movie-about-little-bad-monsters

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84367/90s-movie-about-time-travelers-to-middle-ages-where-dinosaurs-are-considered-dra

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84331/school-trip-that-uncovers-a-town-secret-about-a-large-organisation-experimenting

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84716/identify-time-traveler-cops-movi

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75836/movie-about-a-couple-doing-calculations-to-open-a-door-to-another-world

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84716/identify-time-traveler-cops-movie-80s

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84753/looking-for-an-old-zombie-movie-from-80s

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84810/please-help-me-identify-a-post-apocalyptic-movie

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84822/kids-1980s-movie-tv-show-with-portal-in-basement-to-another-world

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84812/whats-this-movie

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78135/animated-horse-movie-series-1980s-early-1990s-hunted-by-mad-scientist-with-robo

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81196/anime-movie-police-special-unit-fights-demons-with-huge-guns-that-cast-fire-sp

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84972/cant-remember-the-name-of-this-cartoon-from-the-mid-90s

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34680/thriller-of-man-chasing-a-woman-while-time-is-frozen

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72821/comedy-human-like-aliens-disintegrate-a-football-soccer-referee-in-the-middle

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80510/what-is-this-movie-with-the-guy-that-is-possessed

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43750/boy-watching-tv-and-an-elephant-or-a-rabbit-teddy-appears-on-the-tv-and-says-som

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63336/childrens-christmas-movie-where-a-magical-store-grants-you-one-christmas-presen

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/name-of-60s-70s-hammer-film

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82561/horror-movie-which-takes-place-in-an-old-house-with-a-girl-with-powers

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84967/looking-for-a-movie-title-help

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84948/movie-about-aliens-a-son-finding-out-his-father-is-an-alien

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84923/please-help-me-find-this-sci-fi-movie

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84862/identify-this-anime-anime-about-robot-mecha-piloted-by-2-people

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/name-of-cartoon-movie-with-a-unicorn-trying-to-save-other-unicorns

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35830/old-alien-monster-movie-help

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71646/science-fiction-movie-about-parallel-universe

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75061/cartoon-movie-about-a-big-robot-that-help-fight-aliens

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/probably-a-90s-or-early-2000s-movie-with-a-female-alien-mutant-burnt-alive/31650

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73292/animated-film-show-with-mans-journey-of-reverse-civilization-to-an-extent-that

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84015/zombie-movie-wherein-a-man-discovers-an-unfamiliar-word

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/what-french-movie-featured-a-character-repeatedly-sent-back-to-a-fantasy-land

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83804/movie-with-zombie-young-girl-attacking-parents

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83736/animation-about-a-post-apocalyptic-world-an-ocarina-narwhals

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83710/movie-about-a-drilling-on-earth-thats-ends-wrong-causing-a-part-of-earth-flying

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83618/space-movie-with-one-real-apple

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted.

Comment: Are we just going to make a massive list of potentially thousands of questions we want? Seems mildly inefficient.

Comment: @amflare - I don't think it's going to run into those sorts of numbers, but what if it does? These questions are on-topic and oftentimes quite answerable. We should want them in whatever volumes we can grab before they get binned

Comment: Valorum, @Edlothiad, whoever else is interested: is this list complete now, or does it need more editing? Ideally I'd like to get our list wrapped up and sent *before* the M&TV mods do the mass deletion over there.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I think this is pretty much all of them. Unless I'm mistaken, we're not overly interested in those that are already long since solved.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've not looked particularly well, but I trust Valorum's judgement on the matter

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, the moderators over there are aware of the ongoings here and would surely at least ask for updates on the issue before doing anything definite, especially since they have openly agreed that this is reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Valorum how you are doing the search? some key words or manually checking them all ?

Comment: @Erosennin - I'm using OP's custom searches and scrolling through looking for words like "aliens" and "robots"

Comment: @Erosennin Yes, I'd say that question is about speculative fiction and therefore OK here. The kind of machines it refers to don't really exist yet, so that makes it at least kinda sci-fi.

Comment: Also, you guys need to stop getting into these comment arguments with each other. Valorum - OK, you don't like what the M&TV people have been doing with ID questions. The proper place to complain about that is on [movies.meta.se], not random passive-aggressive comments here on meta.SFF. @Erosennin - no need to make things personal. Non-constructive comments about how bad another site's policies are will be deleted if flagged, so you don't even have to respond to such at all.

Comment: @Randal'Thor ok added my ID, anyways few in the list are the question which have 17 upvotes and answer have 22 upvotes, so what criteria you guys are setting? As migrating question which will never going to delete seems pointless.

Comment: @Erosennin Yeah, we seem to be currently at stage 1 of [Shog's list](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4103/27759), getting a list of questions which would be good on SFF. Stage 2 is where the M&TV people vet the list to see which questions they want to keep. Once this list is complete, should I post it on M&TV meta for vetting, or is the test as simple as checking Q&A scores?

Comment: I was not clear about what criteria you guys picked here but I though it should include only the one which will be deleted and are unresolved. How you guys will send it is upto you guys or we can talk about in TL someday.

Comment: @Erosennin - I went through in a hurry because I was under the impression that these were imminently going to be deleted. If there are any posted in error (e.g. answered and ticked), just remove them.

Comment: That’s what I am saying from so many comments and I didn’t even chekced who submitted that one. I am fine with migrating the one which we will be deleting later but not the rest. Thanks for getting the point finaly.

Comment: @Randal'Thor .... we are aware the list is here, we're about to vet the list and pass it to the people who will migrate. No need to post on M&TV. Thanks!