# 54 story identification questions incoming from Movies & TV at 23:00 UTC 2017-02-05

Tags: discussion, status-completed, story-identification, migration

This is just a heads-up: per the request of the membership of this site, I'll be moving [54 ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/which-id-questions-do-we-want-from-movies-tv/11660#11660) from the Movies & TV site to Science Fiction & Fantasy today.

### What does this involve?

As part of the batch migration process, each question will be locked and deleted on Movies & TV, then recreated here.

- All non-deleted answers will be migrated along with each question.
- All votes on posts scoring >= 0 will be migrated (but attributed to the system)
- All posts scoring < 0 will be reset to a 0 score and have no votes initially.
- Tags on migrated questions will be preserved *if* they already exist on Science Fiction & Fantasy at the time of migration.
- Additionally, I will apply the [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) and [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) tags to all questions during migration; in this way there will be no untagged questions resulting from this.

#### Tags currently used on these questions that will be preserved:

- animation
- anime
- cameo
- crossovers
- horror
- time-travel
- western

#### Tags currently used on these questions that will be stripped during migration

- action
- character
- comedy
- documentary
- fantasy
- identify-this-episode
- identify-this-movie
- identify-this-tv-show
- romance
- science-fiction
- short-films
- spy-movie
- thriller

If you want any of these tags to be preserved, **you must create them *here* prior to the start of migration at 23:00 UTC today!**

### After the migration is complete

I will post a list of links to all migrated questions here; at that point, any necessary editing can be performed to bring them in-line with this community's standards.

---

If you have any questions or concerns, please post them here prior to the start of the migration process at 23:00 UTC today; this will be the only mass migration of ID questions from MTV to SFF, so once begun no additional questions can be added to or removed from the list.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, and also for automatically applying the [tag:story-identification] tag to all these questions! Due to that, we may not need to do any retagging on this end at all. But just to make sure: **once migrated, will these questions immediately appear at the top of the "active" tab on SFF?** I guess it doesn't matter that much, since there'll be a list on meta anyway for manual review, but good to confirm in advance.

Comment: It's been a few years since I last did this, @Rand - and honestly, I don't remember. I'm *pretty sure* they'll only appear if you have the tab open **during the migration** (and click the live update banner), but I'm not going to guarantee that. Aside: if you're around at 23:00, you should totally open the homepage and watch the live update ticker - it's like a lunar eclipse: rare, weird, and ultimately disappointing.

Comment: Will they have the movie tag?

Comment: No, @user14111. Should they?

Comment: I think it would make sense, but as usual I suppose I'm a minority of one. Personally, I think that if we're trying to find a story, it helps a lot to know if we're looking for a movie or a novel or a short story (which may not be clear from the body of the question), but that's probably just me. Also, the tag might make it easier for us non-movie-goers (all one of us) to ignore the movie-id questions.

Comment: Makes sense; the [tag:movie] tag guidance explicitly calls out the story-id combo as an appropriate use for the tag. I'll add it to the list.

Comment: Until you get a TV-show... ;-) But maybe that's included in the `movie` tag anyway.

Comment: @TARS - We can sort those manually.

Comment: As TARS gives a nod to, some of the questions listed for migration are about movies and [some](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68644/animated-series-that-tells-stories-based-on-fairy-tales-by-grimm-brothers-hans) are about TV shows. Please *don't* add the [tag:movie] tag to all of them. If we want media tags on them, we can add them manually; better to have relevant tags missing than wrong tags included. (Sorry for the confusion! @user14111 I agree media tags are useful, but we have two separate media tags for screen stuff.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Valorum has a point, though, that most of them will likely be movies anyway and it might be eaiser to fix the ones that aren't rather than all of them.

Comment: This is less of a problem than it sounds, @Rand - of the 54 questions marked for migration, 52 have [identify-this-movie], 3 have [identify-this-tv-show] and 1 has [identify-this-episode] (yes, this means some jackass used multiple tags on a couple of questions). There are 50 that have *only* the [identify-this-movie] tag - so the expedient way to do this is to just add the [movie] tag to those 50 and leave the rest with only [story-identification]. Yes, chances are these will *all* have to be edited eventually, but since some folks around here get tetchy about edits I'll do what I can.

Comment: OK, great! If it's easy for you to auto-add tags with that level of precision, then `identify-this-movie` -> [tag:movie] and `identify-this-tv-show`/`identify-this-episode` -> [tag:tv] would be perfect. (I'm not too worried about edit tetchiness here; this is enough of a once-in-a-lifetime event that we should be able to cope with a messed-up front page for a few hours.)

Comment: Not gonna touch the TV ones, @Rand - I suspect they're bogus anyway, and in the case of episode you'll need to edit to add the series.

Comment: Also the bounty offered on those questions is also restored to those who offered it.

Answer (score 10):

Migration is complete. The following questions now live here:

- [Please help me identify a post apocalyptic movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180705)
- [Sci-Fi movie about a shapeshifter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180706)
- [A Documentary or Short film set in Medieval Europe about a king who impales enemies and a Scientist that gives electric shocks to corpses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180707)
- [Can't remember the name of this cartoon from the mid 90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180708)
- [Horror movie which takes place in an old house with a girl with powers.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180709)
- [Zombie Outbreak movie with a cure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180710)
- [What show did Yakko, Wakko, and Dot make frequent silent cameos in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180711)
- [Identify Time traveler cops movie 80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180712)
- [Old Asian movie about foreseeing the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180713)
- [movie about aliens / a son finding out his father is an alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180714)
- [90s movie about time travelers to middle ages where dinosaurs are considered dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180715)
- [Movie about a drilling on Earth thats ends wrong causing a part of earth flying away?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180716)
- [Horror movie about a demon (or telekinetic ?) boy who kills his family members](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180718)
- [Short Horror Movie (6 mins?) on Youtube](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180719)
- [Thriller of man chasing a woman while time is frozen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180720)
- [Children's Christmas Movie where a magical store grants you one christmas present](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180722)
- [Probably a 90s/or early 2000's movie with a female alien/mutant burnt alive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180723)
- [Name of 60s/70s Hammer(?) Film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180725)
- [A Korean horror movie in 2004 about a ghost trying to protect her unborn baby from medical experiments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180726)
- [Science fiction movie about parallel universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180727)
- [Anime movie, police special unit, fights demons with huge guns that cast/fire spells](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180730)
- [Please help me find this Sci Fi movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180732)
- [Animation about a post-apocalyptic world, an ocarina, narwhals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180733)
- [Movie about little bad monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180734)
- [Comedy: Human-like aliens disintegrate a football (soccer) referee in the middle of the game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180736)
- [Looking for an old zombie movie from 80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180737)
- [Zombie movie wherein a man discovers an unfamiliar word](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180738)
- [What's this movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180739)
- [Cartoon Movie about a big robot that help fight aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180740)
- [Movie with zombie young girl attacking parents](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180742)
- [Identify this movie about ghouls in a desert and a car stonehenge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180744)
- [Identify this anime - Anime about robot/mecha piloted by 2 people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180745)
- [Looking for a movie title. Help?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180746)
- [Animated film about a group of people from a television show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180747)
- [Movie about ants that eat everything and grow to be huge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180751)
- [I remember important parts of this movie but not the title?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180752)
- [What is this movie with the guy that is possessed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180753)
- [Space Movie with one real apple](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180754)
- [Animated film/show with man's journey of reverse civilization to an extent that he goes naked and hunts for food](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180755)
- [Low budget D-list movie with werewolf, emo guy, and mystical girl of his dreams](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180756)
- [Boy watching TV and an elephant or a rabbit teddy appears on the TV and says something](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180757)
- [Old Alien/Monster movie, Help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180759)
- [French film where the wife/girlfriend changes every morning after sex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180760)
- [Movie about a group of monster disguised as human attacking a building](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180761)
- [kids 1980's movie/tv show with portal in basement to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180762)
- [help me identify this horrible vampire movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180763)
- [Name of cartoon movie with a unicorn trying to save other unicorns?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180764)
- [School trip that uncovers a town secret about a large organisation experimenting on young children](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180765)
- [Movie about a couple doing calculations to open a door to another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180766)
- [Animated horse movie/series 1980s-early 1990s, hunted by mad scientist with robot dog](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180768)
- [60's or 70's western horror film that goes from B/W to color](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180770)
- [Animated series that tells stories based on fairy tales by Grimm Brothers, Hans Christian Andersen and others](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180771)
- [What French movie featured a character repeatedly sent back to a fantasy land?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180772)
- [Identify a short animated movie about a walking tree in red shoes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180774)